# Mongo DB Error while Updating - error on remote shard - caused by cursor id

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-compass, mongodb-shell

I have about 8 Million Documents in my Collection.
And I want to remove the special Characters in one of the fields.
I will post my Statement below.
I am using the mongo shell in the Mongo db compass tool.
The update is working about 30-50 Minutes and then throws the following error:

**MongoServerError: Error on remote shard thisisjustforstack.com:27000 :: caused by :: cursor id 1272890412590646833 not found**

I also see that after throwing this error, he did not update all documents.

```
    db.getCollection('TEST_Collection').aggregate(
[{
    $match: {
        '1List.Comment': {
            $exists: true
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        '1List.Comment': 1
    }
}]
)
.forEach(function(doc,Index) {doc.1List.Comment=doc.1List.Comment.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9 ]/g, '');
db.TEST_Collection.updateMany({ "_id": doc._id },{ "$set": { "1List.Comment": doc.1List.Comment } });})
```

Can somebody please help to get this update statement working without running in some sort of timeout? I have read something about noCursorTimeout() but I am not sure on how to use it with my statement and using it in the shell.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Cursor timeout can't be disabled on individual aggregation cursors.

But you can set on global config:

```
mongod --setParameter cursorTimeoutMillis=3600000    #1 hour
```

Anyway I think dividing the task in small batches is a better option

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So I can just execute the command you wrote in my mongo db shell? And after that try my update again?

How would you divide it into small batches?
I mean like take the first 100.000 Documents? But how to tell him in next batch to not take the same documents again?

Comment: Try to use some other field to split the work